# Counting records from table that appear is one but not other: MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

I have a two simple tables

**users**

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | gender | birthdate |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

**userpreference**

```
+----+------------------+-----------------+
| id | preference value | preference type |
+----+------------------+-----------------+
```

Question:

I want to query all people who have not listed a specific preference value such as 'shopping'.This includes all people who have not listed any preference types as well so that column could be null, however since userpreference's column 'id' references users as a foreign key, I also want to include in my count all people who don't show up in the second table (user preference)?

Total # of people who do not have preference value 'shopping' as their preference value:

Here is what i have tried:

```
SELECT
(
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userpreference.id) FROM userpreference
WHERE  preferencevalue != 'shopping')
+
(
SELECT COUNT(users.id)
FROM users
WHERE users.id NOT IN
(SELECT userpreference.Id
FROM userpreference )
)
AS'Total'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Count(*)
From Users
Where Not Exists   (
                    Select 1
                    From UserPreference As UP1
                    Where UP1.id = Users.id
                        And UP1.PreferenceValue = 'Shopping'
                    )
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, from the inner parenthesis are you first getting all the people that do have 'shopping' listed as their preference value then counting from that result all the people from the the users table that do not show up using 'id' as the check?

Comment: @Warz - This is a correlated subquery where the inner query references something in the outer query. An Exists expression works by returning true if even one row in the subquery is returned for each user. The only way the Exists subquery would return a row is if the given user has at least one preference and one of those preference rows is "shopping". By using Not Exists, I'm say either there are no preference rows for the given user or no rows for "shopping".

Answer (score 0):

Try a RIGHT JOIN, that will include all people who dont show up in the second table

SELECT * 
FROM  `Users` 
RIGHT JOIN Userpreference ON ( users.`userID` =  Users.`userID`) 
WHERE preference_value =  'shopping'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

SELECT COUNT(DISTINT U.id) FROM users U NATURAL LEFT JOIN userpreference UP
  WHERE UP.preferencevalue IS NULL OR UP.preferenceValue != 'shopping';

The LEFT JOIN should bring in all the users records whether or not they have a UP record.

Comment: left join give records in both only when there is a match in the on, i think youare thinking of a right join

Comment: Here's the document I was basing that on:  The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table_name1), even if there are no matches in the right table (table_name2).